# Java: Recursive Search of TreeModel via it's UserObject field?

Tags: java, jtree

I have a Jtree using DefaultTreeModel, each individual node contains a UserObject containing various string fields.

I would like to find and select a node by doing a recursive traversal until it finds the DefaultMutableTreeNode with UserObject matching one of it's fields and programmatically select that node.

Are there any examples involving searching via DefaultMutableTreeNode's UserObject fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DefaultMutableTreeNode has [depthFirstEnumeration()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#depthFirstEnumeration%28%29) and [breadthFirstEnumeration()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#breadthFirstEnumeration%28%29). Call the one you desire, iterate through the enumeration until you find the node that has the `UserObject` you want.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode theNode = null;
for (Enumeration e = root.depthFirstEnumeration(); e.hasMoreElements() && theNode == null;) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
    if (whatIWantIs(node.getUserObject)) {
        theNode = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: this helped me a lot! and worked fine! but please add the definition of root which should be somehting like this : myTreeModel.getRoot()