# Java TreeNode while statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, jtree, treenode

I am working on code for a java TreeNode. I will like to do a while statement to loop through from the root of the tree to all subsequent nodes and update numbers. I can do this with an if statement but this only loops through the first nodes and ends there.

```
    if
    (node.getChildCount() > 0)
    {
        updatenumbers(node);
    }
```

I tried this while statement but this causes an abrupt stop of the program and does not update the tree, no errors or exceptions thrown. I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
    while
    (node.getChildCount() > 0)
    {
        updatenumbers( 0, node);
    }
```

This is the code for updatenumbers

```
 private void updatenumbers(int _index, MutableTreeNode _node) {
    int count = _node.getChildCount;
    for (int i = _index; i < count ; i++){
        node.setindex(i);
    }
```

Comment: We don't know what your TreeNode looks like nor what `updatenumbers` does. Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: Where are you traversing the child nodes?

Comment: @RJadhav what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you are operating on only one node in the while loop, does it ever point to the child node?

Comment: @Eran i updated the question, I did not feel it was needed because that portion of the code is large does exactly what i want. As i stated the if statement works but only loops through the first child node but does not continue to the children of the child... if you get me

Comment: @RJadhav I believe that is what i want to achieve..

Comment: So you need to write node=node.left() or node=node.right() or some equivalent form of it in the while loop.

Comment: As @Rjadhav has mentioned, you're missing the part of the code where the node actually references it's children.  Is this a binary tree or some other kind of tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the root node:

```
MutableTreeNode rootNode = //whatever
```

Then you can use an `ArrayList` as a queue like object to do a `while` loop over the tree.

```
ArrayList<MutableTreeNode> queue = new ArrayList<MutableTreeNode>();
queue.add(rootNode)
while(queue.size() > 0){
    MutableTreeNode tempNode = queue.get(0);//access first element only
    updatenumbers(tempNode);  //update children of just this single node
    queue.remove(0);//remove from queue

    //now add the children of tempNode
    queue.add(tempNode.left);
    queue.add(tempNode.right);
}
```

In this example, I assume it's a binary search tree.  You may want adjust the adding of children part based on what the tree actually is.

Now for this method `updatenumbers`.  You don't need to pass the starting index if it's always going to be `0`.  What your issue here is that you're setting the index of the current node and none of the children.  You want to get the child from the `node` (ex.  via custom method `getChild(i)`).

```
private void updatenumbers(MutableTreeNode node) {
    int count = node.getChildCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++){
        node.getChild(i).setindex(i);//you need a getChild method or something similar
}
```

**Update**:  Since it was just revealed you are using [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html), these two sources for `JTree` that may help:

- [Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557186/java-recursive-search-of-treemodel-via-its-userobject-field)
- [Source 2](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0313.html)

Comment: Thanks this is what i was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise the following mechanism.

1) Replace the while loop by a function

2) Initialize node to the root element. call the function with Initialized node.

3) Inside the function use getChildCount() as a base condition.

4) Recurse through the left and right child

Assuming it is a Binary Tree